# Howto effectively change path's width?

Tags: inkscape, path

I'm very beginner in InkScape, and have this kind of design:

[image]

Currently "line" width is ~20px:

[image]

I want to achieve 40px (so basically twice large as now) width, **without** growing canvas dimensions.

This is a path, how can I effectively do this with a "complex" drawings like this?

Taking into account that it also has some curves:

[image]

I know I can calculate coordinates with some math fun (`sin`, `cos` etc), but I'm looking for some easier way of doing this.

Comment: Does dynamic offset help? See a demo [here](https://inkscape.org/~JurgenG/%E2%98%85using-dynamic-offset-in-inkscape).

Comment: That's exactly I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: You also can use the option break appart which will give you two stars, then select snap to the center, reduce the width-height of the inner star, drag it to center and use the excusion option. You will have the shape with a thicker border. You can calcualte the width of both stars to obtain the exact with.